# What does the: = '-'; or ='/' means in strchr(I know it does locate work and strrchr of last occurence)?

Tags: c, strchr

What does the `= '-';` or `= '/'` mean in `strchr` (I know it does locate work and `strrchr` of last occurrence)?
This code does create two files.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fpA = fopen("output_A.txt", "w"); 
    FILE *fpB = fopen("output_B.txt", "w"); 

    char *strA = ",-/"; 
    char temp[100]; 
    char str[5][60] = { { "summer is coming!" },
                        { "vacation will let you chill out" },
                        { "and, have a nice time" },
                        { "and, stay fit" },
                        { "and, wish you the best" }, };
    
    fprintf(fpA, "%s\n", str[0]); 
    fprintf(fpB, "%s\n", str[1]);

    fclose(fpA); 
    fclose(fpB); 

    fpA = fopen("output_A.txt", "r"); 
    fpB = fopen("output_B.txt", "w"); 

    *(strchr(str[2], ' ')) = '-'; 
    *(strrchr(str[2], ' ') + 1) = '/'; 

    strtok(str[2], strA); 
    strcpy(temp, strtok(NULL, strA)); 

    str[1][8] = '\n'; 
    str[1][9] = '\0'; 
    strncat(temp, str[1], strlen(str[1])); 

    if (strcmp(str[3], str[4]))
        strcat(temp, str[3]);
    else
        strcat(temp, str[4]); 

    fprintf(fpA, "%s", temp);
    fprintf(fpB, "%s", temp);

    fclose(fpA);
    fclose(fpB);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Is the printing to file really relevant for the question? The code would be a lot shorter if you just print to stdout (using `printf()`) instead of to two files. See [mre].

Answer (score 5):

The statements

```
*(strchr(str[2], ' ')) = '-'; 
*(strrchr(str[2], ' ') + 1) = '/';
```

basically substitute `'-'` to the first space occurrence, and `'/'` to the character next to the last space occurrence.

The first substitution:

1. `strchr` returns the pointer to the first occurrence of the searched character (`' '`)
2. `*` operator access that pointer
3. the assignment substitutes the character `'-'`

The second substitution:

1. `strrchr` returns the pointer to the last occurrence of the searched character (`' '`)
2. The pointer is incremented, and after that it points to the next character (**dangerous action**: what if the space whas the last character of the string?)
3. `*` operator access the pointer
4. the assignment substitutes the character `'/'`

The string `str[2]`, originally *`"and, have a nice time"`* will be changed into *`"and,-have a nice /ime"`*.

**Warning:** you need to check `strchr` and `strrchr` return values, as they can return `NULL` if the searched character is not found (check [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) out).
If that's the case, dereferencing the pointer will lead to *Undefined Behavior* (probably a segmentation fault on modern computers), making your program crash.

Comment: @Eronsee I missed that '+1'. A'll adapt the answer accordingly. It's not a bog deal if you know how pointers work.

Answer (score 1):

It searches for `' '`, then it assigns `'-'` to the position it found the first/last occurrence of `' '` (depending on `strchr`, `strrchr`). I don't really know why would it do that, but that's what the code is doing.
Sidenote: `strchr`and `strrchr` return `NULL` when no match for `delimiter` is found in the string. If the string were to have no spaces, your code would be segfaulting.
An improvement could be:

```
char* aux = strchr(str[2], ' ');
if (aux != NULL)
    *aux = '-';
```